# Reduce spacing between tr elements in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email, email-client

I have an email template that displays well in most email clients except that the it renders tables poorly in outlook.
There is too much spacing between the "tr" elements of the table in outlook desktop 2016. Please how do I fix this?
Attached is an image of what it looks like on outlook desktop 2016(i.e the problem) and how it looks in outlook web (What I want it to look like) respectively.

[image]
[image]

The entire source code can't be displayed in stackoverflow so I have shared a dropbox link to the HTML. https://www.dropbox.com/s/58i9scmnnmrqsix/EmailTemplate.zip?dl=0

Thank you.

Comment: did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the font size for the coloured boxes and add the boxes as table with cells of different color and a specific height. You can use padding and align to center the tables in the parent cell.

**OR**

you can give the cell a line-height

```
<td style="font-size: 35px" align="right">
<span style="color:#275100; font-size:35px; padding-right:40px; line-height: 15px;">
&#9632;</span>
</td>
```

Cheers